# full-width tables in multicolumnar text

Tags: floats, two-column, multicol

If I create a `table` in `twocolumn`, the text on the second column overlaps the right half of the table. If I use a `table*`, whether with `twocolumn` or `multicols`, it instead is moved to the next page. `table`s in `multicols` simply disappear.

I'd like to have a top-aligned table with two-column text below it. How can this be done sanely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing in principle that prevents what you want from ocurring, (the document below show that it's possible) but float placement is a funny thing, so the reason you can't get what you want might have to do with how the correct placement of the float is calculated in your particular document.  The `float` package can provide some extra help on that end, providing an `[H]` option to a float to force it in a particular place.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for nonsense text
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{1in}p{1in}p{1in}p{1in}p{1in}}
\hline
Some text & Some text & Some text & some text & some text\\
Some text & Some text & Some text & some text & some text\\
Some text & Some text & Some text & some text & some text\\
Some text & Some text & Some text & some text & some text\\
Some text & Some text & Some text & some text & some text\\
Some text & Some text & Some text & some text & some text\\
Some text & Some text & Some text & some text & some text\\
\hline
\caption{A table}
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: The results look reasonable, though the placement is a bit unpredictable. Eh, I guess it works.